# powershell send a table to gmail

Tags: powershell, gmail

I have a table generated by powershell, I used to be able to send the table to exchange as a `html` in email body. but now, we have migrated to gmail and the table shows in gmail is just all `html` code or csv code. After some digging, looks like gmail wont support what I am trying to do. But I tried to copy the table into gmail directly and i received it successfully as no format changes.

As an alternative, I can have the table attached as html or csv files but i still want to have it in email body.

Is there anyway that I can still send my table to gmail from powershell?

```
$myTable = {PS scripts}

$EmailBody = $myTable | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$EmailTo = @("me@gmail.com")
$EmailFrom = "notifications@gmail.com"
$Subject = "Notifications"
$Body = $EmailBody
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
# $filenameAndPath = "C:\temp\test.csv"
$SMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage($EmailFrom,$EmailTo,$Subject,$Body)
# $attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($filenameAndPath)
# $SMTPMessage.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("notification@gmail.com", "xxxxxx");
$SMTPClient.Send($SMTPMessage)
```

Comment: **Plain text**: `$EmailBody = $myTable | Out-String` or **HTML**: `$myTable | ConvertTo-Html -As Table`

Comment: @JosefZ you should add that as an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class MailMessage is looking for a single string for the body. You can read about the class in the [documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0(v=vs.110).aspx). Your current `$Body` variable is an array of strings.

```
public MailMessage(
     string from,
     string to,
     string subject,
     string body
)
```

Convert your `$Body` variable to a single string by passing it to `Out-String` like @JosefZ mentioned in your comment:

```
$EmailBody = $myTable | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-String
```

Based on your comment. It's looking like you wanted an HTML table:

```
[String[]] $To = "me@gmail.com"
[String] $From = "notifications@gmail.com"
[String] $Subject = "Notifications"
[String] $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$Credential = Get-Credential -UserName "notification@gmail.com"
$myTable = {PS scripts}
$EmailBody = $myTable | ConvertTo-Html | Out-String

Send-MailMessage -Body $EmailBody -BodyAsHtml -To $To -From $From -Subject $Subject -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Credential $Credential -UseSsl
```

Comment: Also, you should look into using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet. It makes things a lot easier.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the contents of the table has been received, but the table itself has been removed, there is no cell at all. How can I keep the cells as well?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You were converting `$myTable` to the comma-separated values format. Did you want it as a Text-based or HTML table?

Comment: The table itself, I mean the cells, lines are not in gmail body, but the contents are all in email. just like you see a table in a text file. no acrossed  lines to form that table

Comment: I added a way to make it formatted as an HTML table